# Using Same User Database on Subdomain

Tags: multisite, users, subdomains

How can I create a subdomain that uses the same database as the main domain?

For example, I have `mywebsite.com` which has my main WordPress installation.

I also want, say, `subdomain.mywebsite.com` which has the same user base. I know I can simply use queries on the database, but this seems like an unnecessary workaround. I also need to allow the user to log on to the subdomain, but the account is the same for both the subdomain AND the main domain.

How can I accomplish this? I've tried using multisite but I was unable to figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: *I've tried using multisite but I was unable to figure it out* -- what specific problem did you encounter that you couldn't solve? Multisite allows you to use the same users on multiple sites, and it allows you to set up subdomain-based sites.

Answer (score 1):

Multisite would be the easiest way to achieve this - assuming both sites are WordPress. There are other ways to achieve the same but they are more complicated.

You'll find the instructions here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network